# GitHub Actions - PIPELINE

Tags: java, linux, git, github, pipeline

I have to make a part of a pipeline. On my friends git is already the core of it.

After every commit, there should be added new things to the file. Then this should return file to git. I can see the latest file as one the files in a zip ( as a tag ).

What I want to do? I want to add some code between commit and releasing new file. During that I would like to comment few lines with sed commend in command line ( or any other method), then put it as argument to the robot.jar app (java) and the result return in exactly the same way as before.

I did it locally, but it's hard to put it in github. To be clear:
**After every new commit, I would like to take file opencs.ttl, make some modification, and then return it as it is now.**

My code to comment the file locally in command line:

```
sed -i '15 s/^/                     foaf:name "XYZ".] #/' <file>
sed -i '16 s/^/#/' <file>
sed -i '21 s/^/#/' <file>
```

Code to run the robot:

```
java -jar robot.jar reason --reasoner HermiT --axiom-generators "PropertyAssertion" --input openCS/output_opencs.ttl --output output_opencs2.ttl;
```

My friends pipeline (https://github.com/OpenCS-ontology/OpenCS):

```
name: "pre-release"

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  pre-release:
    name: "Pre-release"
    runs-on: "ubuntu-latest"
    container: ghcr.io/opencs-ontology/ci-worker:main

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          path: opencs

      - name: "Package ontology"
        run: python /app/package.py opencs package dev

      - uses: "marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@v1.2.1"
        with:
          repo_token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          automatic_release_tag: "dev"
          prerelease: true
          title: "Development build"
          files: package/*


##########################################################
      PROBABLY HERE SHOULD BE MY CODE (?)
##########################################################


      - name: "Prepare ontology files for commit"
        run: |
          mkdir output_files
          gzip -cd package/opencs.ttl.gz > output_files/opencs.ttl
          gzip -cd package/opencs.rdf.gz > output_files/opencs.rdf
          gzip -cd package/opencs.nt.gz > output_files/opencs.nt
      - name: "Push the files to the Github Pages repository"
        uses: "cpina/github-action-push-to-another-repository@main"
        env:
          SSH_DEPLOY_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_DEPLOY_KEY }}
        with:
          source-directory: 'output_files'
          destination-github-username: 'opencs-ontology'
          destination-repository-name: 'opencs-ontology.github.io'
          user-name: ci-worker
          target-directory: /releases/latest
          target-branch: main
```

I did it locally and I can convert it using my code, then I can input it to the robot.jar and 'reason' it. Now I have no idea how to do the same things with git actions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Github does not always know when you commit stuff. But Github can only run Actions when it knows about an event, and that is a change in their hosted repository. That means either you commit via the web interface directly on Github, or you commit in your local git client and push the changes to Github.

Very likely you should add your code after the `Checkout repository` step and before python creates the package in the `Package ontology` step.

Use `run` steps to execute your sed and java commands.
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/essential-features-of-github-actions#adding-scripts-to-your-workflow